# Utility to browse recent files in Windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec, file-management

Does anyone have a suggestion for a recent files browser utility for Windows?

I'm looking for something like NirSoft's RecentFilesView:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/recent_files_view.html

But I want more features. I would like to be able to do filtering. I also do see .sln files in the viewer, but not source code for the solution, like .cs files.

Are there any similar utilities to consider trying?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to give [voidtools' Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) a try.  You'll need the latest alpha build from [the Announcements Forum](http://forum.voidtools.com/viewforum.php?f=9).  Don't be scared off by the "Alpha" label, it's very stable.

You could use some of the [advanced syntax expressions](http://support.voidtools.com/everything/Search_syntax) to find recent files, for example: `recent:ext:sln` to find recently changed solution files.  Though "recent" is pretty liberal, since that will search the entire USN Journal.  The `cd:`, `cw:`, or `cm:` modifiers (for last day/week/month, respectively) might be more appropriate.

You can even save a favorite search syntax as a filter and hotkey it so you don't have to dork around typing the same thing over and over again.  Then you can simply search against the filter to find a particular project quickly.

Now, Everything only matches against path/file names.  It's not a content index, like Windows Search is.  It is *blisteringly* quick though, because it builds its initial index by parsing the MFT directly and keeps it up to date by watching the USN Journal.